# What is the order of $U$? Is $\{1, 7\}$ an orbit from $U$?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Let $G: = S_7$ and $U: = \{(17), (1273)\}$. What is the order of $U$? Is $\{1, 7\}$ an Orbit from $U$?

Attempt:

I know/see $(17)$ has the order $2$ and $(1273)$ the order $4$, but I don't know how to show the order for the subgroup.

Orbit: $1^U = \{1,7\}$ (with $1^{id}= 1, 1^{(1273)}= 2, 1^{(1372)} = 3, 1^{(17)}= 7$), so no orbit?

Comment: If you intend $U$ to be a subgroup (rather than just the two listed elements, the appropriate notation is $\langle (1~7), (1~2~7~3) \rangle$.  You're correct that the $U$-orbit that includes $1$ also includes $2$ and $3$, as well as $7$.